# Java getting average after total per index

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a total of my SCORES and VOTES which I have done no problem. Where I'm getting confused and can't seem to solve is how I would go back through my array of Contestants and get their percent of the total SCORES or VOTES. e.g player 1 has a score of 10 out of a total score of 30, player 2 has a score of 15/30 ect... a running average is not a problem its a real total average I can't seem to wrap my head around. Any advice would be terrific.

```
 package contestscore;
 import java.util.*;

 public class ContestScore {



   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of contesants: ");
    int numContest = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter contestants DANCE SCORE and NUMBER OF VOTES    EARNED: ");
    int[] danceScore = new int[numContest+1];
    int[] numVotes = new int[numContest+1];
    double avgDanceScore = 0.0;
    double avgVoteScore = 0.0;
    double totalDanceScore = 0.0;
    int numContestIndex = 0;
    double avgContestDanceScore = 0.0;
    int totalVotes = 0;
    double avgContestVote = 0.0;

    for(numContestIndex = 1; numContestIndex <= numContest; numContestIndex++)
    {
        danceScore[numContestIndex] = keyboard.nextInt();
        numVotes[numContestIndex] = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("DANCE SCORE: "+danceScore[numContestIndex]);
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF VOTES: "+numVotes[numContestIndex]);


        totalDanceScore = totalDanceScore + danceScore[numContestIndex];
        //avgContestDanceScore = danceScore[numContestIndex]                                                                               /totalDanceScore;
        System.out.println("TOTAL DANCE SCORE: "+totalDanceScore); 

        totalVotes = totalVotes + numVotes[numContestIndex];
        //avgContestVote = numVotes[numContestIndex] / totalVotes;
        System.out.println("TOTAL CONTESTANT VOTE SHARE: "+totalVotes);
```

Comment: Perhaps is only me but I cannot see pass "TOTAL CONTESTANT VOTE" line... i.e. the for loop is not even close.

Comment: Why the "recursion" keyword?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem but can't you just get the total votes by summing votes for all contestants and then find the percentage for each contestant as `vote * 100 / sum of votes`.

Comment: I have the total votes and total dance score. The issue is trying to take the total votes and total score and divide each contestants score by the total of votes and same goes for the score. but I can not reference the correct index for each one.

Comment: Because I thought maybe someone would suggest recursion however I'm still new to it so I think I need to use recursion but I'm not sure how to implement it here.